# I wrote a simple particle filter and it won't work with more than a few hundred particles. I can't tell why

Tags: javascript

I have written a very simple 1d particle filter using javascript and a HTML5 canvas. It seems to work pretty well until the number of particles hits 283. I am not all that experienced with either particle filters or javascript, but I cannot see why 283 is the magic number! Please could someone help?

Edit:

OK, so it seems the magic number isn't fixed between browsers, but if I set `nparticles = 1000` it complains `TypeError: particles[count] is undefined` and I don't know why that should be the case. Any tips would be gratefully received.

```js
var c;
var ctx;

var start_x = 600;
var x_speed = 2;
var dt = 1;
var nparticles = 282;
var gauss_dist;

var particles = [];



function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function drawBackground()
{
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,800,400);
    ctx.fillStyle="#00FF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0,350,800,50);
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(50,300,5,50);
    ctx.fillRect(750,300,5,50);
}


function drawRobot()
{
 ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
 start_x += x_speed*dt;
 if (start_x >= 750 || start_x <= 50)
 {
  x_speed *= -1;
 }
 ctx.fillRect(start_x, 300, 10, 50);
 
}


function getDistanceToNearest(x)
{
 var to_far =Math.abs(x - 750);
 var to_near = Math.abs(x - 50);
 var true_dist;

 if (to_far > to_near)
 {
  true_dist = to_near;
 }
 else
 {
  true_dist = to_far;
 }

 true_dist = true_dist - 25 + 50.0*(Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()) / 3.0;
 return true_dist;
}

function w_gauss(a, b)
{
    error = a - b;
    g = Math.exp(-((error *error) / (2 * 50.*50.)));
    return g;
}

function loop()
{
 var i = 0;
 drawBackground();
 drawRobot();
 
 for (i=0; i < nparticles; i++)
 {
  ctx.fillStyle="#0000FF";
  ctx.fillRect(particles[i].x, 345, 2,2);
 }

 

 var u = getDistanceToNearest(start_x);
 var weights = [];
 var wsum = 0.0;

 for (i=0; i < nparticles; i++)
 {
  var distance = getDistanceToNearest(particles[i].x);
  var w = w_gauss(u, distance);
 // console.log(""+w);
  weights.push(w);
  wsum += w;
 }

 //console.log("Wsum = "+wsum);
 var weights_norm = [];
 var trimmed_particles = [];

 for (i=0; i < nparticles; i++)
 {
  var w_norm = weights[i] / wsum;

  if (w_norm > 0.0001)
  {
   weights_norm.push(w_norm);
   trimmed_particles.push(particles[i]);
 //  console.log(""+w_norm);
  }
  
 }

 particles = [];
 for (i=0; i< trimmed_particles.length; i++)
 {
  particles.push(trimmed_particles[i]);
 }

 //particles = trimmed_particles;

 console.log("Number of particles remaining = " + weights_norm.length + " " + particles.length);

 var cummul = [weights_norm[0]];
 for (i=1; i < weights_norm.length; i++)
 {
  cummul.push(cummul[i-1]+weights_norm[i]);
 // console.log(""+cummul[i]);
 }


/*
 for (i=0; i<particles.length; i++)
 {
  console.log(particles[i]);
 }
*/

// console.log("Beginning Resampling");

 var resample = [];
 for (i = 0; i < nparticles; i++)
 {
  var rand = Math.random();
  var count = 0;
  while(cummul[count]<=rand /*&& count < cummul.length*/)
  {
   count += 1;
  }
  //console.log("Count: "+count+ "Trimmed Particles: "+ particles.length);
  //console.log("Cumulative frequency: "+cummul[count]);
  //console.log(particles[count]);
  
  //console.log("x "+particles[count].x+" y "+particles[count].y+" weight "+weights_norm[count]);
  resample.push({"x":particles[count].x + (x_speed+ getRandomArbitrary(-0.5,0.5))*dt, "y":particles[count].y, "weight":weights_norm[count]});
  
 }

 for (i=0; i < resample.length; i++)
 {
  particles[i] = resample[i];
 }
    //particles = resample;
}


function init()
{
 c=document.getElementById("theCanvas");
 ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 
 //gauss_dist = gaussian(50, 50);
 // Take a random sample using inverse transform sampling method.

 //setup initial particle sample

 for (i=0; i < nparticles; i++)
 {
  rand_x = getRandomArbitrary(50, 750);
  particle = {"x": rand_x, "y": 345.0, "weight":1.0/100.0};

  particles.push(particle);
  rand_y = 345;
 }

    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    drawBackground();
    setInterval(loop, 500);
        

    
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
<canvas id="theCanvas" width="800" height="400" style="border:2px solid #FFFFFF;">
</canvas>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `var nparticles = 282;` ?

Comment: If it changes to `var nparticles = 284` then I see a message "filter.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefinedloop @ filter.js:156
11filter.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefinedloop @ filter.js:80"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `loop` the variable `count` gets larger than the length of the array `particles`. If I change the line

```
while(cummul[count]<=rand)
```

to

```
while(cummul[count]<=rand && count < particles.length-1)
```

I can raise `nparticles` without error.

You need to check the array boundaries more often.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think I was so glad that I'd got it working with low numbers I was blind to such a simple cause. I guess it's repeatable because the random numbers are repeatable? I don't know enough about javascript for that, this is for illustrative purposes for my boss!